# Problem handling the session with firebase and nextjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I am trying to manage the session of the user of an administrative panel with the functions provided by firebase 9.22.2 in Next.js, but when I try to delete the user's session when he logs out, using the "signOut" function of "firebase/auth" , this is maintained, so I can't remove the user from the panel, because the session still exists in both firebase and the client.

For example, when I use the "signOut" function of "firebase/auth" and then try to get the session with onAuthStateChanged, it keeps returning it, so the session is never deleted.

The following is the custom hook that I use to get the session:

```
export const useAuthState = (): [SessionProps | null, boolean, () => void] => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [session, setSession] = useState<SessionProps | null>(null);
  const [reloadTrigguer, setReloadTrigger] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (session) => {
      setLoading(true);

      if (session) {
        const user = await getOneUser(session.uid);

        setSession({
          ...session,
          user,
        });
      } else {
        setSession(null);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [reloadTrigguer]);

  return [session, loading, () => setReloadTrigger((n) => n + 1)];
};
```

The following is the custom hook that I use to logout the user:

```
export const useLogout = (): useLogoutProps => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleLogout = async (): Promise<void> => {
    setLoading(true);
    await signOut(auth);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return [handleLogout, loading];
};
```

Lo siguiente es el componente donde invoco al hook para hacer logout, solo es presionar un botón que llama la funcion "handleLogout" dentro del hook.

```
const [handleLogout] = useLogout();
```